# how to skip images with certain class in wordpress function

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have the following function in my theme's function page.  basically what it does is look for any image in the post page and add some spans with css to dynamically create a pinterest button.

```
function insert_pinterest($content) {
global $post;

$posturl = urlencode(get_permalink()); //Get the post URL
$pinspan = '<span class="pinterest-button">';
$pinurlNew = '<a href="#" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$posturl.'&amp;media=';

$pindescription = '&amp;description='.urlencode(get_the_title());
$options = '&quot;,&quot;Pinterest&quot;,&quot;scrollbars=no,menubar=no,width=600,height=380,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no';
$pinfinish = '&quot;);return false;" class="pin-it"></a>';
$pinend = '</span>';
$pattern = '/<img(.*?)src="(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)"(.*?) \/>/i';
$replacement = $pinspan.$pinurlNew.'$2.$3'.$pindescription.$options.$pinfinish.'<img$1src="$2.$3" $4 />'.$pinend;
$content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );

//Fix the link problem
$newpattern = '/<a(.*?)><span class="pinterest-button"><a(.*?)><\/a><img(.*?)\/><\/span><\/a>/i';
$replacement = '<span class="pinterest-button"><a$2></a><a$1><img$3\/></a></span>';

$content = preg_replace( $newpattern, $replacement, $content );
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_pinterest' );
```

it does everything just fine.  but is there a way to have it skip over an image with a certain class name in it like "noPin" ?

Comment: it currently works without the need of jquery.  just php and css3

Comment: It looks like your classes are all static, where would this "noPin" class be stored in the post?

Comment: i can have the blog user add the class on a case by case instance for ones we don't want the pin on.

Comment: Why not just exclude the `pinterest-button` class from the span instead?

Comment: because the way the script works right now is it finds all images in the post, and automatically adds the span with the `pinterest-button`. wouldn't it be easier to say find all images that don't have "noPin" in the class and proceed?

Comment: Oh yeah, my mistake, I was only looking at the second half of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use preg_replace_callback to check if a matched image contains noPin.

```
function skipNoPin($matches){
    if ( strpos($matches[0], "noPin") === false){
        return $pinspan.$pinurlNew.'$matches[2].$matches[3]'.$pindescription.$options.$pinfinish.'<img$1src="$2.$3" $4 />'.$pinend;
    } else {
        return $matches[0]

$content = preg_replace_callback( 
    $pattern, 
    skipNoPin,
    $content );
```

Another image attribute could conceivably contain noPin, if you are concerned about that edge case, just make the test in the if statement more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude the class noPin from the `$pattern` regexp :

```
$pattern = '/<img(.*?)src="(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)"(.*?) \/>/i';
```

Has to become something like

```
$pattern = '/<img(.*?)src="(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)"(.*?) (?!class="noPin") \/>/i';
```

Please check the regexp syntax, but the idea is to exclude `class="noPin"` from the searched pattern. Then your replacement will not be added to these images.

Comment: Your pattern assumes that noPin is the only class applied to the image and that the class attribute is always after the src attribute. This seems like a good time to use preg_replace_callback